# Recursive Functions in Mathematica

Tags: dataset, recursion

I have a dataset with 4 columns and want to take a column and apply some kind of function that subtracts the previous term. So I want to multiply the column by 2 and subtract all of the previous elements. So suppose the column is b[n]={5,5,5,5,6,7,..}.

I want to multiply each element by 2 add this to 100 and then subtract the term so
a[1] = 5x2 +100=110, but the next term would be a[2]=b[2]x2+100-b[1]=5x2+100-5=105,and a[3]=b[3]x2+100-b[1]-b[2]=5x2+100-5-5=100, so it is defined by a[n]=b[n]x2 + 100 - b[n-1]-b[n-2]-....-b[1]. How can I do this in Mathematica? I have b[n] as a column in a dataset right now, so I am not sure how to work with this.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

ds = Dataset[{
    <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 5, "c" -> {1}|>,
    <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 5, "c" -> {2, 3}|>,
    <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 5, "c" -> {3}|>,
    <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> 5, "c" -> {4, 5}|>,
    <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> 6, "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>,
    <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> 7, "c" -> {}|>}];

a[n_Integer?Positive] := 2*b[[n]] + 100 - Sum[b[[k]], {k, 1, n - 1}];

b = ds[All, "b"] // Normal

(* {5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7} *)

a /@ Range[Length[b]]

(* {110, 105, 100, 95, 92, 88} *)
```